# Implementing concurrent read exclusive write model with GCD

Tags: ios, concurrency, ios4, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to understand the proper way of using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) to implement concurrent read exclusive write model of controlling access to a resource.

Suppose there is a NSMutableDictionary that is read a lot and once in awhile updated. What is the proper way of ensuring that reads always work with consistent state of the dictionary? Sure I can use a queue and serialize all read and write access to the dictionary, but that would unnecessarily serialize reads which should be allowed to access the dictionary concurrently. At first the use of groups here sounds promising. I could create a 'read' group and add every read operation to it. That would allow reads to happen at the same time. And then when the time comes to do an update, I could dispatch_notify() or dispatch_wait() as part of a write operation to make sure that all reads complete before the update is allowed to go on. But then how do I make sure that a subsequent read operation does not start until the write operation completes?

Here's an example with the dictionary I mentioned above:
R1: at 0 seconds, a read comes in which needs 5 seconds to complete
R2: at 2 seconds another read comes in which needs 5 seconds to complete
W1: at 4 seconds a write operation comes needing access to dictionary for 3 sec
R3: at 6 seconds another read comes in which needs 5 seconds to complete
W2: at 8 seconds another write operation comes in also needing 3 seconds to complete

Ideally the above should play out like this:
R1 starts at 0 seconds, ends at 5
R2 starts at 2 seconds, ends at 7
W1 starts at 7 seconds, ends at 10
R3 starts at 10 seconds, ends at 15
W2 starts at 15 seconds, ends at 18

Note: even though R3 came at 6 seconds, it was not allowed to start before W1 because W1 came earlier.

What is the best way to implement the above with GCD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, I think. Conceptually, what you want is a private concurrent queue that you can submit "barrier" blocks to, such that the barrier block waits until all previously submitted blocks have finished executing, and then executes all by itself.

GCD doesn't (yet?) provide this functionality out-of-the-box, but you could simulate it by wrapping your read/write requests in some additional logic and funnelling these requests through an intermediary serial queue.

When a read request reaches the front of the serial queue, `dispatch_group_async` the actual work onto a global concurrent queue. In the case of a write request, you should `dispatch_suspend` the serial queue, and call `dispatch_group_notify` to submit the work onto the concurrent queue only after the previous requests have finished executing. After this write request has executed, resume the queue again.

Something like the following could get you started (I haven't tested this):

```
dispatch_block_t CreateBlock(dispatch_block_t block, dispatch_group_t group, dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue) {
    return Block_copy(^{ 
        dispatch_group_async(concurrentQueue, group, block);
    });
}

dispatch_block_t CreateBarrierBlock(dispatch_block_t barrierBlock, dispatch_group_t group, dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue) {
    return Block_copy(^{
        dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
        dispatch_suspend(serialQueue);
        dispatch_group_notify(group, concurrentQueue, ^{
            barrierBlock();
            dispatch_resume(serialQueue);
        });
    });
}
```

Use dispatch_async to push these wrapped blocks onto a serial queue.

Comment: Nick, thank you for your answer! I have not tested your solution yet, but it seems that it will work! (the only correction that seems to be required is that we need to Block_copy the blocks passed to both CreateBlock and CreateBarrierBlock since the blocks are not executed synchronously)

Comment: Apple now provides a barrier block API as of iOS 4.3/OS X 10.7. You need to create a queue with the attribute DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT and whenever you want to add a barrier block to the queue, use dispatch_barrier_async() or dispatch_barrier_sync(). The documentation is in <dispatch/queue.h>.

Comment: @Christopher Nice find! I didn't realise Apple had made that public already.